# disable a button if json is empty

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, json

i need disable a button using css or angular, but it has to be according to the json, i mean if book.BookGanga is empty then the button has to be disabled, if book.BookGanga is not empty then the button has to be shown.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="example{{$index}}" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!--the modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float:right" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title text-center">{{book.Name}}</h2>
                <h5 class="text-center">{{book.Type}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <img ng-src="{{book.ImageUrl}}" class="img-responsive" " />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-10 ">
                                                        {{book.Description}} 
                                                        <hr />
                                                            <h5>Pages: {{book.pages}}</h5>
                                                            <h5>Price: {{book.Rate}}</h5>
                                                            <h5>Language: Marathi</h5> 
                                                            <h5>Binding: Paperback</h5> 
                                                            <h5> Authors: Sri Dr. Narayananandanatha katesvamiji </h5>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer ">
                                                <div class="fb-share-button " data-href="{{book.BookGanga}} " data-layout="button_count " data-size="large " data-mobile-iframe="true "><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore " target="_blank " href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse ">Share</a></div>
                                                <a class="btn btn-success " style="margin-top:-.2em; " href="{{book.BookGanga}} "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart "></span>&nbsp; Buy Online</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: The HTML in question is invalid, possible, copy/paste issue? `class="img-responsive" " />`

Comment: is this using AngularJS 1 or Angular 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using Bootstrap so You can try this as well:

```
<button ng-class = "{disabled : book.BookGanga.length == 0}">
```

[Find out the learning material for the ng-Class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

I hope It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This is a solution for Angular 2, not AngularJS 1

This should suffice (This is a verbose method of checking the existence and non-emptiness of object-properties). The important part is the ngIf, which conditionally creates the DOM element:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:-.2em;" [href]="book.BookGanga" *ngIf="book.BookGanga !== undefined && book.BookGanga !== null && book.BookGanga !== ''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>&nbsp; Buy Online</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ng-disabled="!book.BookGanga"` to your button.

Answer (score 0):

You do it simply by adding ng-disabled attr.